# Fix up shapely polygon object when discontinuous after map projection

Tags: python, maps, geospatial, shapely

This demo program (intended to be run in an IPython notebook; you need `matplotlib`, `mpl_toolkits.basemap`, `pyproj`, and `shapely`) is supposed to plot increasingly large circles on the surface of the Earth.  It works correctly as long as the circle does not cross over one of the poles.  If that happens, the result is complete nonsense when plotted on a map (see below cell 2)

If I plot them "in a void" instead of on a map (see below cell 3) the results are correct in the sense that, if you removed the horizontal line going from +180 to -180 longitude, the rest of the curve would indeed delimit the boundary between the interior and exterior of the desired circle.  However, they are *wrong* in that the polygon is invalid (`.is_valid` is False), and much more importantly, the nonzero-winding-number interior of the polygon does *not* enclose the correct region of the map.

I believe this is happening because `shapely.ops.transform` is blind to the coordinate singularity at +180==-180 longitude.  The *question* is, how do I detect the problem and repair the polygon, so that it does enclose the correct region of the map?  In this case, an appropriate fixup would be to replace the horizontal segment from (X,+180) -- (X,-180) with three lines, (X,+180) -- (+90,+180) -- (+90,-180) -- (X,-180); but note that if the circle had gone over the *south* pole, the fixup lines would need to go south instead.  And if the circle had gone over *both* poles, we'd have a valid polygon again but its interior would be the complement of what it should be.  I need to detect all of these cases and handle them correctly.  Also, I do not know how to "edit" a shapely geometry object.

Downloadable notebook: https://gist.github.com/zackw/e48cb1580ff37acfee4d0a7b1d43a037

```
## cell 1
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import transform as sh_transform
from functools import partial

wgs84_globe = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84')

def disk_on_globe(lat, lon, radius):
    aeqd = pyproj.Proj(proj='aeqd', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84',
                       lat_0=lat, lon_0=lon)
    return sh_transform(
        partial(pyproj.transform, aeqd, wgs84_globe),
        Point(0, 0).buffer(radius)
    )
```

```
## cell 2
def plot_poly_on_map(map_, pol):
    if isinstance(pol, Polygon):
        map_.plot(*(pol.exterior.xy), '-', latlon=True)
    else:
        assert isinstance(pol, MultiPolygon)
        for p in pol:
            map_.plot(*(p.exterior.xy), '-', latlon=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 12))
map_ = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='c')
map_.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)

for rad in range(1,10):
    plot_poly_on_map(
        map_,
        disk_on_globe(40.439, -79.976, rad * 1000 * 1000)
)
plt.show()
```

[image: output of cell 2]

```
## cell 3
def plot_poly_in_void(pol):
    if isinstance(pol, Polygon):
        plt.plot(*(pol.exterior.xy), '-')
    else:
        assert isinstance(pol, MultiPolygon)
        for p in pol:
            plt.plot(*(p.exterior.xy), '-', latlon=True)

plt.figure()
for rad in range(1,10):
    plot_poly_in_void(
        disk_on_globe(40.439, -79.976, rad * 1000 * 1000)
)
plt.show()
```

[image: output of cell 3]

(The sunlit region shown at http://www.die.net/earth/rectangular.html is an  example of what a circle that crosses a pole *should* look like when projected onto an equirectangular map, as long as it's not an equinox today.)

Comment: This is not a trivial question, but it seems you almost got it. Sometimes I just wish the earth was flat, hahaha.. You need to handle the ambiguity by your own, by checking whether the buffer (the `Point(0, 0).buffer(radius)` polygon) in the azimuthal equidistant projection touches one of the poles. By knowing that, you can implement your proposed fixup to the new polygon in the WGS84 projection, before trying to plot it. About the differences in the plotting when you use the map, I don't know, but I imagine the problem will vanish if you only handle the fixed up polygon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manually fixing up the projected polygon turns out not to be *that* bad.
There are two steps: first, find all segments of the polygon that cross the [coordinate singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_singularity) at longitude ±180, and replace them with excursions to either the north or south pole, whichever is nearest; second, if the resulting polygon doesn't contain the origin point, invert it.  Note that both steps must be carried out *whether or not* shapely thinks the projected polygon is "invalid"; depending on where the starting point is, it may cross one or both poles *without* being invalid.

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it works.

```
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, box as Box
from shapely.ops import transform as sh_transform
from functools import partial

wgs84_globe = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84')

def disk_on_globe(lat, lon, radius):
    """Generate a shapely.Polygon object representing a disk on the
    surface of the Earth, containing all points within RADIUS meters
    of latitude/longitude LAT/LON."""

    aeqd = pyproj.Proj(proj='aeqd', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84',
                       lat_0=lat, lon_0=lon)
    disk = sh_transform(
        partial(pyproj.transform, aeqd, wgs84_globe),
        Point(0, 0).buffer(radius)
    )

    # Fix up segments that cross the coordinate singularity at longitude ±180.
    # We do this unconditionally because it may or may not create a non-simple
    # polygon, depending on where the initial point was.
    boundary = np.array(disk.boundary)
    i = 0
    while i < boundary.shape[0] - 1:
        if abs(boundary[i+1,0] - boundary[i,0]) > 180:
            assert (boundary[i,1] > 0) == (boundary[i,1] > 0)
            vsign = -1 if boundary[i,1] < 0 else 1
            hsign = -1 if boundary[i,0] < 0 else 1
            boundary = np.insert(boundary, i+1, [
                [hsign*179, boundary[i,1]],
                [hsign*179, vsign*89],
                [-hsign*179, vsign*89],
                [-hsign*179, boundary[i+1,1]]
            ], axis=0)
            i += 5
        else:
            i += 1
    disk = Polygon(boundary)

    # If the fixed-up polygon doesn't contain the origin point, invert it.
    if not disk.contains(Point(lon, lat)):
        disk = Box(-180, -90, 180, 90).difference(disk)

    assert disk.is_valid
    assert disk.boundary.is_simple
    assert disk.contains(Point(lon, lat))
    return disk
```

The other problem -- `mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.plot` producing garbage -- is *not* corrected by fixing up the polygon as above.  However, if you manually project the polygon into map coordinates and then draw it using a `descartes.PolygonPatch`, that works, as long as the projection has a rectangular boundary, and that's enough of a workaround for me.  (I *think* it would work for any projection if one added a lot of extra points along all straight lines at the map boundary.)

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from descartes import PolygonPatch

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 12))
map_ = Basemap(projection='cea', resolution='c')
map_.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)

for rad in range(3,19,2):
    plt.gca().add_patch(PolygonPatch(
        sh_transform(map_,
            disk_on_globe(40.439, -79.976, rad * 1000 * 1000)),
        alpha=0.1))    
plt.show()
```

[image]